# pegar un formulario a la parte de arriba

Tags: bootstrap

Como puedo hacer para pegar un formulario a la parte de arriba. Existe la propiedad sticky-top y funciona pero para todo el ancho del div general. Únicamente quiero el formulario.`

```html
<div class="row sticky-top" style="margin-top:40px">
          
            <div class="col-1">
            lk
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 mr-3" style="margin-right:40px">
            lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-row">
                       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                           <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                           <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                         <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                             <label for="inputCity">City</label>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
                        </div>
                       <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="inputState">Provincia</label>
                            <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                            <option>Cuenca</option>
                            <option>Ciudad Real</option>
                           </select>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
                         </div>
                     </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="form-check">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                         Check me out
                      </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
        
            </div>
        
        
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La clase [`sticky-top`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#sticky-top) te permite dejar fijo un elemento arriba de la ventana, pero solo cuando hayas pasado por este haciendo scroll, debes incluirlo al elemento que desees que tenga este comportamiento de esta manera:

```
<form class="sticky-top">
    ....
</form>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:40px">

    <div class="col-1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 mr-3" style="margin-rigth:40px">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <form class="sticky-top">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputCity">City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Provincia</label>
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                <option>Cuenca</option>
                                <option>Ciudad Real</option>
                               </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                             Check me out
                          </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Es importante que consideres que `position: sticky` [no está soportado](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#fixed-top) en todos los navegadores.

---

Si por otro lado deseas que esté fijo todo el tiempo puedes utilizar la clase [`fixed-top`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#fixed-top), agregandola al elemento que quieres que tenga este comportamiento, de esta forma:

```
<div class="col-4 fixed-top"></div>
```

Y en tu caso específico debes agregar `left: auto` a tu css para que respete el ancho del div

```
.fixed-top {
  left: auto;
}
```

```css
.one {
  height: 1rem;
  background: #0FF;
}

.two {
  height: 1rem;
  background: #FF0;
}

.three {
  background: #F0F;
}

.fixed-top {
  left: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:40px">

    <div class="col-1 one"></div>
    <div class="col-6 mr-3 two"></div>
    <div class="col-4 fixed-top three">
      <form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputCity">City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Provincia</label>
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                            <option>Cuenca</option>
                            <option>Ciudad Real</option>
                           </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                         Check me out
                      </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Es correcto, pero sólo funciona si hay suficiente contenido en el primer <div class="col-1"> </div>. Si  dejamos vacío,  el form no se pega a la parte de arriba

Comment: Ósea tú quieres que el `form` esté fijo todo el tiempo en la parte de arriba?

Comment: Exacto, que esté fijo cuando hago scroll

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, espero sea lo que buscabas :)

Comment: No me expliqué bien, la idea es que el formulario esté pegado a la parte de arriba, una vez hemos hecho scroll. Digamos que está ubicado por la mitad de la web (en altura) y cuando  llegamos a él, este se queda pegado a la parte de arriba.